# when I trigger onClick useState does not toggle class

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

Tried to solve this problem but nothing works. Trying to do onClick and toggle class on useState but anything get triggered when I do it. Can anyone explain me why it is not working.React seems not to change the state also I cannot see the x that should appear in the button which is the one that should set useState on false. Thanks in advance.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import FilterMenu from "./selectButton";
import FetchRandomBet from "./fetchRandomBets";

function Betslip() {
    const data = [
        {
            value: 0,
            label: "No Filter"
        },
        {
            value: 1,
            label: "Less than two"
        },
        {
            value: 2,
            label: "More than two"
        },
    ]

    const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState(0);
    const [allStakes, setAllStakes] = useState(null);
    const [isActive, setActive] = useState(false);

    const handleChange = obj => {
        setSelectedValue(obj.value);
    }

    const betNow = () => {
        if (!allStakes) {
            const stakes = localStorage.getItem("stakes");
            const jsnStake = JSON.parse(stakes) || [];
            setAllStakes([jsnStake]);
            setActive(isActive);
            console.log('yes')
        } else if (allStakes) {
            localStorage.setItem("stakes", null);
            setAllStakes([])
            console.log('no')
        }
    }

    const closeBet = () => {
        setActive(false);
    }

    console.log(allStakes)

    return (
        <div className="betslip">
            <div className="betslip-top">
                <h1 className="text">BETSLIP</h1>
                <p className="text-two">BET WITH US!</p>
                <div>
                    <FilterMenu
                        optionsProp={data}
                        valueProp={selectedValue}
                        onChangeProp={handleChange}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <FetchRandomBet
                    valueProp={selectedValue}
                />
            </div>
            <Button
                onClick={betNow}
                className="betnow"
                variant="contained"
            >
                Bet Now!
                </Button>
            <div className={isActive ? "bet-show" : "bet-noshow"}>
                <button
                    onClick={closeBet}
                >
                    x
                </button>
                <h1>
                    {allStakes}
                </h1>
            </div>
        </div >
    );
}

export default Betslip;
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve], like a codesandbox

Comment: in betNow you should do setActive(true);

Comment: Oh sorry dude @BabarKhan I haven't seen your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default your active is set to **false** and you have css class shows if active is **true** i think

so in your betNow() :

```js
const betNow = () => {
        if (!allStakes) {
            const stakes = localStorage.getItem("stakes");
            const jsnStake = JSON.parse(stakes) || [];
            setAllStakes([jsnStake]);
            // change to true
            setActive(true);
            console.log('yes');
        } else if (allStakes) {
            localStorage.setItem("stakes", null);
            setAllStakes([]);
            console.log('no');
        }
    }
```